# Running rgsvr32 in program files\myapp seems to fail even when run as admin

Tags: ocx, regsvr32

Our software needs to be able to register an ocx at runtime.  The OCX lives in the program files directory of the app.  I find that if I manually fire up a cmd line as admin and run the command everything works great, however if i fire up our app as admin and let the app try to register the ocx, it fails.  I also notice that the app is able to run regsvr32 successfully when i run it from my build directory, presumably because i own the build dir.  I still have to run as admin though.  Anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong?

Thanks,
brian

Comment: Can you tell us more about the OS it's failing on, any error messages (anything in the event logs)?

Comment: The problem occurs on windows 7 64bit and 32bit.  I'm trying to trap some error messages now and i'm checking the event viewer.  It may fail on other OSes too but im not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is firstly, that i'm sloppy, and secondly that the command line args passed into regsvr32 need to be wrapped in double quotes.  It never occurred to me because i wrote my code like so:

```
string args = "/s " + Path.Combine(MP_xxxx_DIR.FullName, MAP_POINT_OCX) ;
```

when it should have looked like:

```
string args = "/s " + "\"" + Path.Combine(MP_xxxx_DIR.FullName, MAP_POINT_OCX) + "\"";
```

Hope this helps someone else :)